# Debugging problem for a Role instance with Azure Compute Emulator,Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-web-roles, webrole

I create a new service of notification for a webRole
I defined the service in web.config

```
<system.serviceModel><services>
  <!-- Notification Service Definition -->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationServiceBehaviors" name="Paw.Services.NotificationService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Paw.Services.INotificationService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NotificationServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors></system.serviceModel>
```

But when i try to debug and start a new instance of a webrole, the service deploys in ASP.net Server not in Compute Emulator.
I don't know why it is acting like this and the web.config isn't used at all in starting the new instance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as not selecting the cloud project as the Start Project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Not linked to that, i have only 2 endpoints possible, but it is trying to deploy on another endpoint.I put more details

Comment: So, you definitely have the Cloud Project marked as Startup Project in Visual Studio and VS is ignoring that option and running Cassini server instead?  What happens then when you right click the Cloud Project (not the WCF service) and choose Debug > Start New Instance?

Comment: OH Yeah that solved the problem i didn't think about debugging the cloud project instead o_O thanks :)